# How do I install a rails plugin from git via ssh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Installing a rails plugin using the git:// protocol is easy, you just type

```
script/plugin install git://server.local/my_git_repo.git
```

How do I install a plugin from a git repo hosted over ssh?

When I type

```
script/plugin install myuser@myserver.com:plugin.git
```

I get "Plugin not found"

I know it's not a git issue because the installer doesn't even prompt me for my ssh password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script/plugin can not currently handle git over ssh.

Instead you're just going to have to clone the repository manually from the vendor/plugins directory.

```
$RAILS_ROOT/vendor/plugins $ git clone ssh://myuser@myserver.com:plugin.git
```

The plugin script also removes the hidden directories, .git and .git-ignored from the newly cloned copy.